# How can i turn on/off opacity of an object or texture/material?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I'm making an animation with textures, one of them is a shadow, which i need to turn off from 100% opacity to 50% with keyframes, it would be okay to do it with the entire object of the material itself (Eevee) how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can accept the entire object becoming transparent, then use a principled shader.  Alpha is the equivalent of opacity and you can set key frames on it by going to a particular frame in the time line, setting the alpha you want, hovering the mouse over the input field, and typing I to add the keyframe.  If you're using EEVEE you'll have to go to the shader settings and set Blend Mode to Alpha Blend and Shadow Mode to Alpha Hashed.